# why is numpy.fromstring reading numbers wrong?

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing code that uses numpy.fromstring to read arrays from xml element text.

It runs with no error, but what it reads is very strange.

for example

```
import numpy as np

nr = 24
r_string = '''
0.0000    0.0100    0.0200    0.0300    0.0400    0.0500    0.0600    0.0700
0.0800    0.0900    0.1000    0.1100    0.1200    0.1300    0.1400    0.1500
0.1600    0.1700    0.1800    0.1900    0.2000    0.2100    0.2200    0.2300
'''

r = np.fromstring(r_string, count = nr)

print(r)
```

prints the following(garbage)

```
[1.20737375e-153 1.48440234e-076 1.30354286e-076 6.96312257e-077
 6.01356142e-154 1.20737830e-153 1.82984908e-076 1.30354286e-076
 6.96312257e-077 3.22522589e-086 6.01347037e-154 6.03686893e-154
 1.39804459e-076 9.72377416e-072 3.24245662e-086 6.01347037e-154
 6.03686880e-154 1.39939399e-076 1.79371973e-052 1.91654811e-076
 8.54289848e-072 6.96312257e-077 6.01356142e-154 1.20738399e-153]
```

What is going on here?

I will appreciate help here.

Comment: By using the default `sep`, you trigger a deprecated use of the function. From the documentation: _Passing sep='', the default, is deprecated since it will trigger the deprecated binary mode of this function. This mode interprets string as binary bytes, rather than ASCII text with decimal numbers_.

Comment: See the docs: `sep : str, optional
The string separating numbers in the data; extra whitespace between elements is also ignored.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to declare `sep=' '`

```py
>>> r = np.fromstring(r_string, count = nr, sep=' ')
>>> r
array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
       0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
       0.22, 0.23])
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. It is strange that 'sep' is defined as optional in the manual [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)

Comment: As other also explain the default, is deprecated since it will trigger the deprecated binary mode of this function - since version 1.14 - you can also see more about it in document link you have already mentaion above

Comment: @DeenaRoller Happy to help, and I see you're new to SO If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Running `np.fromstring` without the `sep` specified will actually throw the warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs.
```

You need to specify your seperator, like:

```
np.fromstring(r_string, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
       0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
       0.22, 0.23])
```